# how to get the row index on TD click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get the row no and column no of cell on which user has clicked
my code is giving the correct column no but row no always giving 0 and 1

I am using the following code 
   help me to find the reason why giving the row no always 0 and 1

```
<script>
 $('td').click(function(){
 col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
 row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
 alert("row no:"+row+"col no :"+col);
 </script>
```

Comment: Please add your `HTML` code too...Also, what does `JAVA` has to do with your question?
 I've seen you tagged it.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `$(element).index()` to get that element's index within it's siblings

```js
$('td').click(function() {
  var col = $(this).index(),
    row = $(this).parent().index();

  console.log("row index:" + row + ", col index :" + col);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td>Item 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td>Item 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td>Item 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td>Item 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
    <td>Item 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler and faster without jQuery if you use `.cellIndex` and `.rowIndex`.

```
$('td').click(function(){
  var col = this.cellIndex,
      row = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
  alert("row no:"+row+"col no :"+col);
```

As noted by @PatrickRoberts below, old Opera's behavior (version 12 and lower) deviates in that it honors the `thead/tbody/tfoot` order in HTML that you provide, so if you put the `tfoot` above the `tbody` (which is really where it should go), and it has one or more rows, the `tbody` rows will be offset by that much.

The correct behavior is to consider the `thead` at the top and the `tbody` at the bottom, irrespective of where they were defined.

This is no longer an issue in modern Opera since it now uses Chrome's Webkit fork, so the behavior is consistent.

Also note that jQuery's manual `.index()` calculation will only take into account the children of the given `tbody`, assuming that's the context here.

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex), `HTMLTableRowElement#rowIndex` does not demonstrate consistent behavior across browsers, nor does it do the same thing as jQuery would with `$(this).parent().index()` from a `<td>`. You might want to mention that, and explain in a little more detail than I just did.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Updated, though I wonder if that info is out of date since as I mentioned in my edit, Opera now uses Chrome's Webkit fork, so the behavior should be consistent.

Comment: If you can verify that the current version of Opera is consistent with Chrome, you might consider editing the MDN page to state this, since it's a public wiki. That's quite an interesting point.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: Just confirmed with this demo http://jsfiddle.net/t3yfuoop/, Opera's behavior is correct, so version 12 should have been the last faulty version.. I can't update the wiki right now. Hopefully I'll remember later on, or maybe someone will get to it first